# Cant log to vm via Static IP

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, static-ip

i created static IP from File->Host Network Manager
[image]

Then i changed Network Adapter to Host-only Adapter and Select created Static IP address
[image]

Change configurations in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
[image]

Then ran
`sudo netplan apply`

`ip address` shows like
[image]

But cant log from my host machine, it ask for password
Even though i changed user password of server by `sudo passwd k` it doesn't allow me to log in.
[image]

Please point me out the problem here.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Can you try login via authorized_keys.

step 1 : Install `ssh-keygen` on your local machine. Just give enter to all the request.

step 2 : copy the public key `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in the local and paste it in the server location `nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

step 3 : Also run the permission command for authorized_keys 400 or 600 is required. `chmod 600 authorized_keys`.

step 4 : By using direct command `ssh k@192.168.57.1`you can login.